# Linux; Comparar archivos contra repositorio remoto

Tags: php, linux, bash

éste es mi primer post aquí aunque el sitio me ha sido de ayuda muchas veces.

El tema es éste.

Tengo varias máquinas virtuales linux (debian 10) que son distribuidas a los clientes.
Estas vm's se conectan con nosotros cada una por una conexión vpn propia.

Cada vez que es necesario actualizar un script o un archivos en masa, es necesario ingresar a cada vm mediante la vpn para modificar o sobreescribir los cambios necesarios en cada script o archivo.

Si es posible aceptaría sugerencias sobre cómo se podría automatizar esta tarea.
Algo como crear un repositorio externo y que las vm's chequeen si existen o no actualizaciones.

Estas actualizaciones se aplicarían sobre /srv/xxx y/o /var/www/html/xxx de cada vm.

Desde ya muchas gracias a todos.

Comment: Un cronjob en cada VM que corra un rsync contra el recurso remoto (el repositorio donde estarían los archivos en su versión estable)?

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo.
Lo había pensado, pero opté por preguntar, quizá alguien palnteaba alguna otra opción.
Para que sea más eficiente debería montar la carpeta compartida localmente verdad?

Comment: No necesariamente. Para recursos remotos sería `rsync -a ~/dir1 username@remote_host:destination_directory` y se conectaría por SSH

Comment: Perfecto @Alfabravo! 
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Te lo dejo como respuesta por si te sirvió y puedas marcarla como aceptada, así otros sabrán qué pueden hacer si tienen el mismo problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El camino más amable con su tiempo y con las posibles dificultades sería un cronjob en las máquinas virtuales que haga rsync.

Si la conexión es por una VPN y tal, lo más seguro sería hacerlo sobre SSH

```
rsync -a ~/dir1 username@remote_host:destination_directory
```

Y ya con eso, poniendo un directorio en el host con una versión estable de los archivos, las VM siempre van a encontrar los recursos sin que alguien deba sentarse a hacer la actualización. Si se ponen creativos, pueden hacer que el cronjob les notifique por email que actualizó correctamente y que escriba en un log los pasos de cada ejecución :)